# Замена ссылок

Tags: поиск, веб-программирование, ссылки

Сайт сделан на движке jomla. На данный момент своими руками сделал новый движок и планирую запустить и удалить жумлу. К чему приведет изменение всех ссылок? Как поведут себя поисковики?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в джумле у тебя ЧПУ и все ссылочки имеют вид типа **/about.html** или **/folder/link.html**, то почему бы не сделать ЧПУ и в новой твоей CMSке, чтобы все ссылки остались неизменными? Тогда все останется на своих местах и все будут довольны, как юзеры, так и поисковики :)

Ну а если этот вариант не возможен, то изменение всех ссылок приведет, как минимум к 404 ошибке на новом сайте, ну и поисковикам необходимо будет время, чтобы заново проиндексировать твой ОБНОВЛЕННЫЙ сайт. Но это того стоит ;) т.к. он уже будет на ТВОЕМ ДВИЖКЕ, братан ;)